# javascript: changing "multiple" attribute of the "select" element does not work

Tags: javascript, select

Windows 7 64 bit, Chrome version 61.0.3163.100

I have a html page with a listbox:

```
<select id='lst' multiple>...</select>
```

I need to disable multiple items selection for this listbox.
I have a javascript function with this code:

```
lst = document.getElementById('lst');
lst.multipe = false;
```

I have checked in the debugger - the value changed to "false".
But in another function called "onclick", it is "true" again.
And multiple items could be selected with [shift] or [ctrl] pressed.

Comment: maybe a jsbin example would help here. Is the behavior consistent in other browsers ? You mention a function. The "reset" to true inside the function might be caused by a closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
lst = document.getElementById('lst');
lst.removeAttribute('multiple');
lst.setAttribute('multiple', true);
```

```html
<select id='lst' multiple>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

Multiple is based on presence, so you need to remove or set it if need from javascript.

Answer (score 3):

The [`multiple`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple) attribute is a boolean attribute, and, according to the [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute):

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true
>   value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.

Use [`removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) instead:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('select');
element.removeAttribute('multiple');
```

```html
<select id="select" multiple>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
```